# include directive and <jsp:include> attribute name problem

Tags: java, jsp

Why in JSP we write attribute name as **file** in include directive, but as **page**  standard action?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<% include file="target.jsp" %>` will inline the source of `target.jsp` into your page, and then the whole thing will then be evaluated as a single JSP. This is done at JSP compile time. This can be highly optimized by the container, and can have side-effects. For example, if you change the content of `target.jsp`, the container generally will not recompile the JSPs that included it.

`<jsp:include page="target.jsp"/`> will execute `target.jsp` as a seperate JSP, and then include the output of that execution into your page. This is done at JSP execution time. Note that this can refer to any path inside the container, not just a JSP (e.g. you can include the output of a servlet).

Comment: +1 I prefer to use `<jsp:include>` since you can send new request parameters to the included page via `<jsp:param >`.