# How to pass jsp form in to two pages?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a jsp form

```
<form action="../sup/Processor.jsp" method="POST" name="ProjectKey" id="Proje">
```

I want to send this from in to another jsp page. How can i do that

Comment: You want to send to `sup/Processor.jsp` ?

Comment: I send to sup/Processor.jsp qustion is how i send it to another page like sup/Name.jsp

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Because it contain same information it's useless to put same page twice.

Comment: i think you should reconsider your design

Comment: You cannot make this with submiting form, because each HTTP request generates one HTTP response. How browser can determine which one of two responses you want use to display data? If you simple need to make two or more requests then you can use AJAX or use one request with additional processing on server.

Comment: @user1619188 - You can forward data from one page page (chain of requests) via `<jsp:forward/>` action.

Comment: I think he is just trying to run his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is you want to re-use the `<form>` snippet in your other JSPs.

<sub>Please correct me if this is not what you want, I would suggest **providing more information in your question** about what you exactly want to do and why. Thanks</sub>

So you can have your `form` in a JSP, say `my_form.jsp` and then reuse the `my_form.jsp` by using any of the following:

1. Using the `include` directive i.e. static include

   ```
   <%@ include file="my_form.jsp" %>
   ```
2. Using the [`jsp:include`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref1112.html) standard action, this will include the form in `my_form.jsp` in any page at run-time.

   ```
   <jsp:include page="my_form.jsp" />
   ```

In addition here are some more links which can help you understand this better:

1. [include directive and `<jsp:include>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1271329/468763)
2. [Difference between include directive and standard action](http://javapapers.com/jsp/difference-between-jsp-include-directive-and-jsp-include-action/)

I would suggest you go through some good tutorial regarding the concepts of [web-application](/questions/tagged/web-application) and using [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) and [servlets](/questions/tagged/servlets). Our tags on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) have good information regarding what to read and how to dive deep in the topic.

Hope this helps.